# Extend system drive (C:) partition in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-disk

After installing **Windows 10** on C: drive with other programs that partition is getting too close to full.

I want to increase C: drive size, I checked third party software but all are payable.

- EASEUS Partition Master
- Paragon Partition Manager

Is there any free software to do this?

Comment: GParted from a Linux LiveCD? Have not tried it on Windows disks, but it should work. There are several Live distributions featuring this, e.g. SystemRescue.

Comment: Are additional partitions in use directly 'behind' C:, and do you want to preserve their data? Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: Still I do not check **GParted** but I will check soon, just I worried about OS fail or data lost. **Is it working for Windows 10?**

Comment: GParted is not only free it is also free (as in free as a bird, with this software you are free to use it as you wish, to study, copy, modify, use, etc). I have not used it on 10, but I know it works on earlier versions of Microsoft's OSes.

Comment: Why the downvote, is it because they use Microsoft's Windows 10? I so no problem in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 include a built-in functionality in Disk Management to shrink and expand partitions. No more 3rd party utilities needed! It’s worth noting that many third-party utilities will be more feature-rich, but you can do the very basic stuff in Windows without adding anything new.

To get to this utility, you’ll need to use the Start Screen search. Just use the Start Menu or the Control Panel search:
[image]

How to Extend a Partition

In the Disk Management screen, just right-click on the partition that you want to extend, and select “Extend Volume” from the menu.

[image]

On this screen, you can specify the amount that you want to increase the partition by. In this case, I’m going to extend it back to the roughly 50GB size that it was before.

Note that the extend partition feature only works with contiguous space.

[source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: You can only extend the secondary partition. **You can not extend System Boot partition.** [Please check image C drive Extend Volume disabled](//i.imgur.com/QkMexq0.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I may recommend MiniTool Home Partition Wizard, it should be exactly what you're looking for. It allows you to extend any partition including the one you're currently using. The software, if required, will set up a one-time boot loader that will allow go ahead and proceed with the expansion. This software is free but please read their license before using this software.

## [MiniTool Home Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) (freemium)

> MiniTool Partition Wizard is a partition manager software that supports 32/64 bit Windows Operating System.
>
> With the Free Edition, home users can perform complicated partition
>   operations by using this powerful yet free partition manager to manage
>   their hard disk.
>
> Functions include: Resizing partitions, Copying partitions, Create
>   partition, Delete partition, Format partition, Convert partition,
>   Explore partition, Hide partition, Change drive letter, Set active
>   partition, Partition Recovery.
>
> [image: Screenshot of application]

Answer (score 0):

I have also used GParted (special recognition to Izzy in the comments as well). This software is 100% free (see the license for more information), however, to boot into it, you must use a LiveCD or install it on a thumb drive. It does work with any type of Windows including 10 and [this person](https://superuser.com/a/821239/269798) and I have used it many times. I usually use MiniTool Partition Wizard but it that's not enough and has missing features I need, I go straight to GParted. More information about the LiceCD can be [found here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual).

## [GParted](http://gparted.org/) (free)

> GParted is a free partition editor for graphically managing your disk partitions.
>
> With GParted you can resize, copy, and move partitions without data
> loss, enabling you to:
>
> - Grow or shrink your C: drive
> - Create space for new operating systems
> - Attempt data rescue from lost partitions
>
> [image: GParted Main Window]